# Adding a SubView to UITableViewCell doesn't get displayed

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7

I have created my own chart via `drawRect`

```
@interface FTChartsView : UIView

@implementation FTChartsView

-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
   ...
}
```

I have also subclassed the UITableViewCell

```
@interface FTSummaryCellView : UITableViewCell
...
```

Now in the ViewController, when the cells are generated:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"FTSummaryCellView" bundle:nil];
    [[self tableView] registerNib:nib forCellReuseIdentifier:@"FTSummaryCellView"];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   FTSummaryCellView *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"FTSummaryCellView"];
   FTChartsView *chart = [[FTChartsView alloc] init];
   [cell addSubview:chart];
   return cell;
}
```

The cell gets the chatrView added as subview. However chartsView's `drawRect`, is never breaking and hence never showing.

What am I missing here please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot about `setFrame`.

```
- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MyCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyCell"];
    TView *chart = [[TView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 30, 30)];
    [cell addSubview:chart];
    return cell;
}
```

Works perfectly for me.

Ty for `[[self tableView] registerNib:nib forCellReuseIdentifier:@"FTSummaryCellView"];`. I never known about this method)

### Edit

You must add subview to content view as I known. But all works for me without that.

```
[cell.contentView addSubview:chart];
```

Comment: ahh now that I instantiate my chart class via `initWithFrame`, its drawRect is actually hit. And I see a black rectangle in the cell. So I need to define that rectangle's position to make it appear exactly where I want it to be. Thanks for the tip. Now one major problem I come across is that only the cells inside the view have the custom drawing. The cells outside the view that are dragged into screen remain empty. Even though I have already added  `[cell setNeedsDisplay];
    [chart setNeedsDisplay];
    [cell.contentView setNeedsDisplay];`

Comment: Ignore the second part of my comment. It was due a mistake in my code. It works perfectly. So `initWithFrame` was the solution after all. thanks +1

Answer (score 0):

Here is a stab in the dark... after adding the FTChartView to the cell... maybe try doing:

```
 [chart setNeedsDisplay];
```

Sometimes that works if you have a custom drawRect method.

Maybe even

```
[chart.view setNeedsDisplay];
```

Comment: Thanks. I have `[cell setNeedsDisplay];
    [chart setNeedsDisplay];` already without joy. But I can't do `[chart.view setNeedsDisplay];` It says view not found on chart.